# Installing Ubuntu (or /any/ linux os, for that matter) freezes upon installation

Tags: system-installation

I have a rather peculiar issue. When I attempt to install ubuntu on my desktop tower, or any linux os, It attempts maybe the first 2 seconds of the install then freezes.

There is a huge error message screen that just spits out stuff much, much faster than I can read *any of it*.

**What I have tried so far**

- Using two different USB install drives
- Pretty much any and ever ubuntu version, as well as the latest: Arch, Debian, Linux mint and manjaro.
- Changing the ISO a multitude of times.
- All the recommendations when a black screen normally appears (noacpi off and all that stuff, in a multitude of different combinations).
- Using both USB 2.0 and 3.0, for every single port on my computer.

At this point, I simply do not know what to do. I normally never ask questions on stackexchange or the like seeing as 999/1000 someone has run into the issue before. A few installations ago, I was attempting to install Ubuntu and I believe after about eight attempts I managed to spot the error message "Softlock up on CPU#N for X seconds". Random cpu, random amount of seconds. Haven't seen that in a while.

What is infuriating is I don't want to dual boot, I just want to be completely rid of windows. My computer currently has windows 8.1 installed on the ssd boot disk. It actually used to have ubuntu originally when I first built the computer but I installed windows over it so that I could play games, however the compelling work environment that linux offers for development has brought me back over to wanting it as my primary OS again.

Additionally, the only thing that has changed in the computer has been the fact that I added a GTX 780 to the build. Nothing else. It worked prior with that installed too.

If you guys want *any* other information, I'd be more than willing to provide it as I am absolutely at my wit's end at this point.

**Further info**
Pretty much the only button at the boot-install screen that *doesn't* result in a black screen with a tiny purple bar on the far left is the memory test screen. This did not happen before, it's actually letting me run a memory test this time so I'm letting that run. So far so good.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same problem by doing this:

1. at the grub menu choose `install Ubuntu` and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit.
2. look for line that start with `linux` add `acpi=off` between `quiet and splash`.
3. then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to execute the grub command.
4. now you are able to install Ubuntu but if you use a touchpad it will be disabled and you need to use a mouse instead.
5. after the install you need to restart and you need to repeat everything above when you are starting Ubuntu in grub.

then finally when Ubuntu is started do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

After this reboot the system.

Good luck, hope it helps for you as well.